# What is the meaning of "shark upon the ships" in following statement?

Tags: phrases, expressions

What is the meaning of "shark upon the ships" in following statement? Does it say something more than "people are very bad in Port *Said*"?

> "*Some nice-looking faces in the streets, but a good many ruffians ; not
>   so bad though as Port Said, where the people simply exist to shark
>   upon the ships.*"
>
> From Adam's Peak To Elephanta (1892)

Answer (score 1):

[To shark](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shark):

> - To take advantage of others for personal gain, especially by fraud and trickery. (AHD)

- The passage refers to people who behave like "sharks" when they are embarked on ships.

Comment: I don't think this is right. I think it refers to people who behave like sharks, not when they are embarked on ships, but when they sell things to or buy things from ships or sailors.

Comment: @PeterShor - yes, that makes sense, probably we need  more context.